# Fatal error Allowed memory size exhausted with WooCommerce WordPress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I keep getting the error below when adding an item to my cart. It just started showing up and I have more than enough memory left in the database. I have searched online to find a solution and I have tried all of them: editing the php.ini, editing .htaccess and putting a php.ini in wp-admin. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 125829120 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 65484 bytes) in
>   /homepages/22/d515555101/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php
>   on line 259

Comment: Perhaps some part of the script is consuming more memory than its specified by default. You can increase it using `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');` Or better to find out the reason why its taking so much memory.

Comment: increase the memory for PHP [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-21)

Comment: Thanks for the comments back. This has been helpful in finding a solution. Looking in to why it is taking up so much memory.

Comment: try looking at /var/log/httpd/access_log or error_log. also enable mysql slow query log and tailf /var/log/mysql/slow-log; it'll help you figure out what's taking up so much memory when adding item to cart.

Answer (score 4):

Find the default-constants.php file on wordpress\wp-includes folder.
Try changing line 23 :

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '40M');
```

to :

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WooCommerce Tickets plugin by Modern Tribe? If so, then you need to download the latest version (3.9.2) and install that. (You'll likely need to deactivate and delete the old version). For some reason it's not giving alert that an upgrade is available.

I had tried everything suggested on other forums and finally found this solution and it was the only thing to solve my problem. Hope it helps you!